# jQuery change callback context

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering how to change the context of a a jQuery callback function so that `this` is the same as it is in the parent function.

Take the following example:

```
var context = this;
console.log(context);

element.animate(css, speed, type, function () {
     var new_context = this;
     console.log(new_context);
});
```

How would I make it so that `new_context` is equal to `context`?

I realise I could do this:

```
var new_context = context;
```

But is there a better way of telling the function to use a different context?

Comment: Why don't you use context to refer to parent context?

Comment: @Adil No real reason I was just wondering if I missed a trick and could save creating a few variables.

Comment: hm var new_context = context?

But I'd rather use context itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize closure:

```
var context = this;
console.log(context);

element.animate(css, speed, type, function () {
     var new_context = context; // Closure
     console.log(new_context);
});
```

You can also do this:

```
// First parameter of call/apply is context
element.animate.apply(this, [css, speed, type, function () {
     var new_context = this;
     console.log(new_context);
}]);
```

Comment: So this is what closure is... I never properly understood what it was.